# How can I make this webpage responsive where should I start

Tags: html, css, fonts, responsive-design, display

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\home.css">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-brand">
            <img  src="\images\Yummy Cookies-logos_black.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our Journey</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Place Your Order</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>

        </ol>
    </nav>
    <section class="video-greeting">
        
        <video autoplay loop muted src="videos\pexels-olya-kobruseva-5264841.mp4"> </video>
        
       <a href="">Place Your Order</a>



        
       
        
    </section>

    <section class="cookie-tab">
        <img class="first-image"width=300px src="images\delish-ms-fields-cookies-024-1544735513.jpg" alt="">
        <p class="first-lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur mollitia, voluptates laudantium adipisci deserunt consequuntur sequi assumenda veritatis quaerat id asperiores saepe est. Unde magnam dolores rem, neque tempora perspiciatis.</p>
        
       
        <p class="second-lorem">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, quibusdam est facere, alias rem perferendis animi, architecto nobis at iste aliquam quis adipisci error? Itaque porro quam odit est laboriosam obcaecati soluta sapiente earum quas rerum, tempora magni excepturi maiores saepe aperiam ipsum eaque quasi libero vero corrupti dolorum dolor! Vero magni recusandae cum nesciunt aliquam quo debitis placeat eos reprehenderit harum repellendus, dolore rerum doloribus, accusamus, aliquid corporis laborum praesentium molestias neque porro magnam. Quam corrupti delectus provident cum vitae sed earum nihil nemo. Cupiditate ab, voluptate aspernatur ullam libero dolorum animi qui nisi eaque impedit, a tempora veniam.</p>
         <img class="second-image"width=300px src="\images\soft-sugar-cookies-5.jpg" alt="">
    </section>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cookie&display=swap');


body{
    font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* navbar ________________ */
nav{

    background-color: pink;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 12;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-height: 120px;

    
    
    



}

.nav-brand{

width: 100px;
display: inline-block;
}

.nav-brand img{
    width: 100%;
    
}

nav ol{

    display: flex;
    gap: 5px;

    
   
    margin-right: 20px











}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    
    

    
    

    
    
}

nav li a{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding:2px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    
    
    
    

}

nav li a:hover{
    color: white;
}


/* video greeting */


.video-greeting{
    margin-top: 90px;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    
    


}




.video-greeting video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;

    object-fit: cover;

    


    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.video-greeting a {

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: pink;
    background-color: rgba(251, 231, 239, 1);

    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;

    top: 43%;
    left: 39%;
    
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    
    

}


.cookie-tab{

  
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    display: grid;
    
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    gap: 20px;
    
    

}

.cookie-tab img{
    
    border: 2px black solid;
    width: 100%;
    
    
    display: block;

    
}

.cookie-tab p{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
   
    

}
```

I want to make this page more responsive I know I can use the @media tool but I am wondering if there is better approach from changing types of units. Like how to scale the font as the page increases in size or how to make certain elements such as the the video greeting element not to move just to stay in one place. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this code will work on smaller devices. use it as a starting point

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav {
     flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

basically the styling will apply at this width or less

Comment: sorry but my code is built for mobile I am trying to expand it for desktop displays